# Django - if statement in template not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django site using the following models:

```
class User_Posts(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=CONFIG['MODEL_SETTINGS']['User_Posts']['message_length'])
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    character = models.ForeignKey(Characters, related_name='user_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    non_bot = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default = 'user')


class Bot_Replies(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=CONFIG['MODEL_SETTINGS']['Bot_Replies']['message_length'])
    character = models.ForeignKey(Characters, related_name='bot_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_origin', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    non_bot = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default = 'bot')
```

in my view, i am passing:

```
    user_posts = User_Posts.objects.filter(created_by = request.user, character__pk = pk)
    bot_posts = Bot_Replies.objects.filter(created_by = request.user, character__pk = pk)
    posts_list = sorted(
        chain(user_posts, bot_posts),
        key = lambda x: x.post_date, reverse = False
        )[-10:]
```

and passing 'posts_list' to the template as 'posts'. My template is looping:

```
  {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="card mb-2">
      <div class="card-body p-3">
        <div class="row">
          {% if post.non_bot == 'user' %}
            <div class="col-2">
              {{ post.created_by }}
            </div>
          {% else %}
            <div class="col-2">
              {{ post.created_by }}
            </div>
          {% endif %}
          <div class="col-2">
            {{ post.message }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

but the if statement never works, it always passes to the "else" clause. If I print out the variable non_bot value on my screen, it shows the correct bot/non-bot values but for some reason I cannot access them in the template. All other values I display show up correctly. Any ideas why? Thank you! (as an FYI, I initially had this as a boolean field, which also didnt work)

Comment: `post.non_bot` instead of `posts.non_bot`?

Comment: and i think you should keep it as a boolean field :)

Comment: sorry, just a typo. the variable is 'post', but still not working

Comment: nope, another silly typo. working now, thank you! if you write an answer i will accept it

Comment: It looks like your "if" and "else" are the same